Where does the equation for the gradient using least squares regression come from?
I'm trying to understand how the equation for the slope of a least squares regression line (below) was derived. I can't quite grasp where it originates from. Any help and pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks
$ m= S_{xy}/(S_x)^2 $
Where
$ S_{xy} = \sum{xy} - \frac{(\sum{x})(\sum{y})}{n} $
and
$ (S_{x})^2= \sum{x^2} -\frac{(\sum{x})^2}{n} $

Have a look at any book introducing linear regression. Good work so far, keep that momentum going!

minimize $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (y_i-(mx_i+b))^2$ w.r.t. $m$ and $b$

Can you add a sentence or paragraph explaining what you think each of those equations is/means, what you heard they mean but don't understand? That will probably help a lot. In some sense @J.W.Tanner 's hint contains all the information you need but if you don't have a good grasp of Calculus that might be to ofar of a jump. Adding the sentences I requested gives us a better idea of what you know/what you're stuck on/how to communicate with you

To derive the formula for $m$, minimize $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(y_i-(mx_i+b))^2$ with respect to $m$ and $b$.
Set $\dfrac\partial{\partial b}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(y_i-(mx_i+b))^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n2(y_i-(mx_i+b))(-x_i)=0$
and $\dfrac\partial{\partial m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(y_i-(mx_i+b))^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n2(y_i-(mx_i+b))(-1)=0.$
From here we get $$m\sum_\limits{i=1}^nx_i^2+b\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_ix_i\tag1$$
and $$m\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i+bn=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i\tag2.$$
To eliminate $b$, multiply (1) by $n$ and (2) by $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$ to get
$$mn\sum_\limits{i=1}^nx_i^2+bn\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i=n\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_ix_i\tag{1'}$$
and $$m\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i \sum_{i=1}^n x_i+bn \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\tag{2'}.$$
and subtract to get
$$m\left(n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2-\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\right)=n\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_ix_i-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i.$$
Can you take it from here?
